# tengo un error para buscar un personaje por ID en la funcion (searchCharacter),Como lo resuelvo?

Tags: array, go

> services.go

```
var characters []domain.CharactersBB
func searchCharacter (id int)(domain.CharactersBB,error){
var c domain.CharactersBB
for_,a := range characters{
   for _ , b := range a {
         if c[a][b].CharID ==c[a][b].id {
               return c , nil
         }
    }
}
return domain.CharactersBB{} ,ErrorCharactersNotFound
```

}

> domain.go

```
type CharactersBB []struct {
CharID int ´json:"charid"´
Name string ´json:"name"´
Birthday string ´json:"birthday"´
}
```

> Tengo estos errores non-integer slice index a(índice de corte no entero a)
>   invalid operation: c[a][b] (type struct { CharID int "json:\"char_id\""; Name string "json:\"name\""; Birthday string "json:\"birthday\""} does not support indexing)(no admite indexación)
>   services/services.go:79:25: non-integer slice index a(índice de corte no entero a)
>   services/services.go:79:28: invalid operation: c[a][b] (type struct { CharID int "json:\"char_id\""; Name string "json:\"name\""; Birthday string "json:\"birthday\"" } does not support indexing)(no admite indexación)

Comment: Ya traduje la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo bien lo que pretendes hacer pero el error es porque al iterar sobre `characters` te devuelve en `a` un `struct`:

```
{
    CharID int ´json:"charid"´
    Name string ´json:"name"´
    Birthday string ´json:"birthday"´
}
```

y esta no es *iterable* como te dice el error `non-integer slice index a`.

De todos modos si haces un `range` (recorres el array) luego utilizas `c` cuando tienes el elemento disponible...

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer, que es devolver el CharacterBB que contiene  en su array un struct con el mismo CharID que el id que pasas por parámetro, tienes que cambiar la comprobación.

```
...
if c[a][b].CharID ==c[a][b].id {
  return c , nil
}
...
```

por

```
if b.CharID == id {
  return b, nil
}
```

Estas recorriendo los elementos del array de CharactersBB, que a su vez es un array de structs, por lo que el CharacterBB que declaras como c no te haría falta.